# Can't find variable: onClassifyPress

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native, it gives me this error ( Can't find variable: onClassifyPress ) and I don't know how to solve it.
I want to have a screen with the two buttons I have implemented there.
My guess is that I have miss something in the onClassiyPress function,but I am not sure of that.
Please help me.

```
import React, {
    useState
} from 'react';
// Import core components

import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Button,
    Alert
} from 'react-native';

import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker';


const App = () => {

  onDocumentPress = async() => {
    try {
        let urlOfS = 'http://10.0.2.2:5000/fileupload'; // your url
        const res = await DocumentPicker.pick({
            type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
        })
        if (res.size < 50000000) {
            let data = new FormData();
            data.append('file', res)
            try {
                const responseOfFileUpload = await fetch(urlOfS, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        Accept: 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    },
                    body: data,
                })
                if (responseOfFileUpload.status == 200) {
                    let responseInJs = await responseOfFileUpload.json();
                    let fileName = responseInJs.fileName; // file name which will be        sent from backend
                    let raspuns_server = responseInJs.answer;
                    console.log(raspuns_server);
                    alert('Upload Succesfull');
                } else {
                    alert('Upload Failed');
                }
            } catch (err) {
                alert('Upload Failed - Request nu a fost trimis');
                console.log(err, 'error in upload');
            }
        } else {
            alert('File size should not exceed 50 MB');
        }
    } catch (err) {
        if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
            alert('No document selected');
        } else {
            throw err;
        }
    }
  }

  onClassifyPress = async() => {
    let urlOfS = 'http://10.0.2.2:5000/classy';
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button title="select document" onPress={this.onDocumentPress} />
      <Button title="classify song" onPress={this.onClassifyPress} />
    </div>
  );

};

export default App;
```

Comment: remove `this`. this is required in class based component only, you are using function. Also define `onClassifyPress` like this: `const onClassifyPress = async () => {}`

Comment: Now it gives me an error regarding div : view config getter callback for component 'div' must be a function (received 'undefined'). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter

Comment: why do you have a `div` in a `react-native` codebase

Comment: I see that without div, it gives me an error in that return

Comment: use `View` instead of `div`. div is for React, not React Native

Comment: Thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This keyword refers to the current instance of the class,
to access a method or property of a class you could do this through this keyword.
So creating onClassifyPress as you did is making a method that requires an instance of the class to be accessed, but as your component is function make your functions inside it like this:

```
  const onClassifyPress = async() => {
    let urlOfS = 'http://10.0.2.2:5000/classy';
  }

  // and call it without this keyword like this
  <Button title="classify song" onPress={onClassifyPress} />
```

Comment: Now it gives me an error regarding div : view config getter callback for component 'div' must be a function (received 'undefined'). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter

Comment: Because you are using <div> tag in react-native , instead use View https://reactnative.dev/docs/view